# What is an example of using aliasing to your advantage when recovering an input signal?

Tags: nyquist, aliasing

Suppose you have an arbitrary analog input signal $x_a(t)$ guaranteed to have frequencies within a bandwidth $[f_1,f_2]$ Hz.

Suppose your sampling frequency $F_s$Hz, and sample $x_a(t)$ to produce $x(n)=x_a(\frac{n}{F_s})$.

Then by the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), you can successfully recover (or reconstruct) the signal so long as $f_2 < \frac{F_s}{2}$. Otherwise you will experience aliasing and cannot recover the original signal $x_a(t)$.

It appears (from [this article](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2015/09/25/beyond-the-first-nyquist-zone)) that there are "tricks" that can be employed that take advantage of aliasing scenario and can still recover the signal $x_a(t)$ completely.

The specific part of the article of concern is pasted below:

> Using Nyquist aliasing as benefit
>
> The trick is to use the aliasing (or frequency folding) to your
>   advantage. By undersampling the data converter, higher-frequency
>   content will be aliased into all of the lower Nyquist zones (see
>   Figure 2). You will need to make absolutely sure that nothing ends up
>   in the lower bands – any noise or frequency components in the lower
>   zones will also be aliased into the first Nyquist. The good news is
>   that the data rate from the data converter is only a fraction of the
>   required RF input sample rate if this were a first Nyquist system.
>   Under sampling greatly reduces the data rate of the samples supplied
>   to the digital signal processor (DSP) or FPGA.

Could somebody explain this to me? Why is the Texas Instruments link not violating Nyquist's Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can successfully recover (or reconstruct) the signal so long as $f_2<F_s/2$

Nope. The sampling theorem says that you need 2 samples per Hz of bandwidth, so in this case you'd need

$$Fs > 2*(f_2-f_1)$$

For more info on how this works google "bandpass sampling" or just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersampling.

The basic idea is that sampling creates a periodic repetition of the original spectrum with a period of $F_s$. As long as none of the repeated spectra falls on the same frequencies as the original spectrum, you don't get aliasing.